# Spark scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon is not a valid external type for schema of string

Tags: scala, apache-spark

What is possible reason why this code doesn't work and how to fix it? Yes, f1, f2, f3, f4 fields are not using, but in productive code getList has an argument xml_data, so I pass xml_data field to method and get List[AnyRef]

```
def getList: List[AnyRef] = {
  List("string",
   new Integer(20),
   Decimal(BigDecimal(10000), 10, 2),
   Timestamp.valueOf("2021-01-01 10:00:00"),
   List("1","2","3"),
   List(1,2,3),
   List(Decimal(BigDecimal(10000), 10, 2)),
   List(Timestamp.valueOf("2021-01-01 10:00:00")),
   null,
   List(null))
}

...

val schema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("string", StringType),
  StructField("int", IntegerType),
  StructField("decimal", DecimalType(10, 2)),
  StructField("timestamp", TimestampType),
  StructField("array_string", ArrayType(StringType)),
  StructField("array_int", ArrayType(IntegerType)),
  StructField("array_decimal", ArrayType(DecimalType(10, 2))),
  StructField("array_timestamp", ArrayType(TimestampType)),
  StructField("array_int", ArrayType(IntegerType)),
  StructField("array_string", ArrayType(StringType))
))

val encoder = RowEncoder(schema)

import spark.implicits._

List((1, 2, 3, 4))
  .toDF("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4")
  .as[Rec]
  .map(rec => {
    Row(getList)
  })(encoder)
  .show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Row` doesn't take a `List` but a varargs parameter. To expand that list into varargs you have to use this weird type ascription `_*`. Otherwise the whole list will be interpreted as the first (and only) parameter.

```
List((1, 2, 3, 4))
  .toDF("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4")
  .as[Rec]
  .map(rec => {
    Row(getList :_*)
  })(encoder)
  .show()
```